# What is the max JVM memory value that still performs well?

Tags: java, performance, memory

I run a Java application with an Xmx value of 8GB at this moment. Garbage collection times are fine and ok for the overall performance (this includes FullGC).

Does anybody have experience with setting the Xmx value to 16GB or even 32GB? Can such memory settings be applied without worrying about the performance?

Environment:
Ubuntu 14, JRE 1.7

Comment: I've set `Xmx=120GB` on server, and what? Strange question indeed

Comment: It depends completely on your application.

Comment: It depends completely on your application, your computer, ... It is a completely meaningless question.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "performance": throughput? latency? As a very rough rule of thumb: GCs will not usually hurt throughput too badly, but they may have an effect on latency (different GC models weight those two differently, 'though).

Answer (score 1):

I've run servers up to 50/60Gb with few problems. It's *all dependent on your use case*, however, and whether such issues as GC pauses will impact your scenario.